How to manage environment variables in Angular apps when deploying on Kubernetes with Docker?
Compile-time Configurations have Limitations In certain scenarios (like CI/CD pipelines or containerized environments), it can be inconvenient to rebuild the app every time the environment changes. So, how can we solve this problem and set environment variables in Kubernetes with Docker?
For the production build, I run the command ng build --configuration production and in this build, it includes the apiServer URL and a secret key, it is exposed in front-end if i use browser developer tools. So, how can we manage these things securely?
here is my environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain:"",
  databaseURL:"",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
  },
};



@Fariya Rahmat Can you help me with this?

Managing environment variables securely in Angular applications deployed with Kubernetes and Docker requires runtime configuration instead of compile-time configurations. This approach eliminates the need to rebuild the app whenever environment variables change and prevents exposing sensitive data in the frontend.
Steps to Implement Runtime Configuration :
Remove Sensitive Data from environment.prod.ts
// environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
};

Create a Runtime Configuration File Like assets/config/config.json
{
  "firebaseApiKey": "",
  "firebaseAuthDomain": "",
  "firebaseDatabaseURL": "",
  "firebaseProjectId": "",
  "firebaseStorageBucket": "",
  "firebaseMessagingSenderId": "",
  "firebaseAppId": "",
  "firebaseMeasurementId": ""
}

Fetch Configuration at Runtime: Modify your main.ts to fetch the configuration file before bootstrapping the app.
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

fetch('/assets/config/config.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((config) => {
    (window as any).__env = config; // Attach config to the global window object
    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }
    platformBrowserDynamic()
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });

Access Config Variables in Your App: Create a service to access the environment variables.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigService {
  getEnv(key: string): string {
    return (window as any).__env[key] || '';
  }
}

Kubernetes ConfigMap Integration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: angular-config
data:
  config.json: |
    {
      "firebaseApiKey": "your-key",
      "firebaseAuthDomain": "your-domain",
      "firebaseDatabaseURL": "your-url",
      "firebaseProjectId": "your-id",
      "firebaseStorageBucket": "your-bucket",
      "firebaseMessagingSenderId": "your-sender-id",
      "firebaseAppId": "your-app-id",
      "firebaseMeasurementId": "your-measurement-id"
    }

Inject the ConfigMap into the Docker Container: Mount the ConfigMap into the assets/config directory in the container.
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volume
    mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config
    subPath: config.json
volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
      name: angular-config

